# import error no module named tkinter issue for latest Python version 3.8.2

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to resolve the error:

> ImportError: No module named tkinter

however no solutions from previous questions seem to be working at all.

I have tried :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

and tkinter installed successfully, yet the issue remains.

I've tried making the `t` in `tkinter` uppercase as i'm using Python 3.8.2 yet that did not work.
I have also tried reinstalling/repairing Python as `tkinter` supposedly comes with the latest Python versions.

Attempting to open my file with `python3 main.py` results in the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "main.py", line 95, in 
>           window = Tk()
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2023, in **init**
>           self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>       _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

I have also tried installing `tkinter` through its installer for
 Windows, the installer works yet I still have the same issue. I have also tried updating my `pip`. Running `pip list` does not display `tkinter`.

Below is my main.py file.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import tkinter.font as font
import os.path
from modify_data_pandas import get_column_headings
from modify_data_pandas import scan_file


#Closes window
def close_window():
    window.destroy()

#Function checks if the file exists, changes label
def is_valid(*args):
    if os.path.isfile(input_file_path.get()):
        valid_confirm_lbl.config(text="File Found!")
        valid_confirm_lbl.config(fg="green")
        return 1
    else:
        valid_confirm_lbl.config(text="File Not Found")
        valid_confirm_lbl.config(fg="red")
        return 0

#Sets progress bar value
def setbar(value):
    progress_bar['value'] = value

#Gets the current selection in the list box
def add_selection():
    if is_valid():
        items = headers_listbox.curselection()
        already_selected = headers_listbox_selected.get(0, END)
        for item in items:
            if headers[item] not in already_selected:
                headers_listbox_selected.insert(END, headers[item])

#Gets the current selection in the list box
def remove_selection():
    if is_valid():
        items = headers_listbox_selected.curselection()
        pos = 0
        for i in items :
            idx = int(i) - pos
            headers_listbox_selected.delete(idx,idx)
            pos = pos + 1

#Add all items in listbox to selection
def add_all():
    if is_valid():
        items = headers_listbox.get(0, END)
        for item in items:
            if item not in headers_listbox_selected.get(0, END):
                headers_listbox_selected.insert(END, item)

#Remove all items in selection listbox
def remove_all():
    if is_valid():
        headers_listbox_selected.delete(0, END)

#Scans the file for sensitive data
def scan():
    if is_valid():
        print("Scan")
        change_row, change_col, change_type = scan_file(input_file_path, headers_listbox_selected.get(0, END))


#Anonymizes the file
def anonymize():
    if is_valid():
        print("do anonymize")

#Opens file dialog to pick a csv file
def choose_file():
    input_file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV files","*.csv"),))
    input_file.delete(0, END)
    input_file.insert(END, input_file_name)

#Analyzes the file for sensitive data
def analyze_file():
    if is_valid():
        headers_listbox.delete(0, END)
        headers_listbox_selected.delete(0, END)
        global headers
        headers = get_column_headings(input_file_path)
        #headers = list of column headings from selected file
        for item in headers:
            headers_listbox.insert(END, item)
        #Call function that checks each cell for sensitive data
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

#Configure GUI Window
window = Tk()
window.title("CSV Anonymizer")
window.geometry("413x800")
lbl_frame = Frame(window)
lbl_frame.grid(column=0, row=1)
listbox_lbl_frame = Frame(window)
listbox_lbl_frame.grid(column=0, row=5, pady=5)
listbox_frame = Frame(window)
listbox_frame.grid(column=0, row=6)
listbox_btn_frame = Frame(window)
listbox_btn_frame.grid(column=0, row=7)
listbox_btn_frame_2 = Frame(window)
listbox_btn_frame_2.grid(column=0, row=8)

#Label: "File:"
input_file_prompt = Label(lbl_frame, text="File:",anchor=W, justify=LEFT)
input_file_prompt.pack(side = LEFT)
input_file_prompt.config(width=20)

#Label: "File Not Found / File Found!"
valid_confirm_lbl = Label(lbl_frame, text="", anchor=E, justify=RIGHT)
valid_confirm_lbl.pack(side = RIGHT)
valid_confirm_lbl.config(width=20)

#Create stringvar so file path is verified upon change
input_file_path = StringVar()

#Text Field to display/enter Input File Name
input_file = Entry(window, textvariable=input_file_path, width=10)
input_file.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=20)
input_file.config(width=40)

#Checks if the file is valid upon change
input_file_path.trace_add("write", is_valid)

#Button: "Click to Select a File", opens file browser to select a file
choose_file_btn = Button(window, text = "Click to Select a File", command = choose_file)
select_btn_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
choose_file_btn['font'] = select_btn_font
choose_file_btn.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx=20, pady=20)
choose_file_btn.config(height=3,width=30)

#Button: "Use This File", starts analyze_file func
use_file_btn = Button(window, text = "Use This File", command = analyze_file)
use_file_btn.grid(column = 0, row = 3, padx=20, pady=(8, 10))
use_file_btn.config(width=13, height=2)

#Label "Select the columns you would like to anonymize"
select_columns_lbl = Label(window, text="Select the columns you would like to anonymize")
bold_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=15, weight='bold')
select_columns_lbl['font'] = bold_font
select_columns_lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)
select_columns_lbl.config(width=40)

#Labels state listbox titles
column_headings_lbl = Label(listbox_lbl_frame, text = "Column Headings")
column_headings_lbl.pack(side=LEFT)
column_headings_lbl.config(width=20)
selected_column_headings_lbl = Label(listbox_lbl_frame, text = "Selected")
selected_column_headings_lbl.pack(side=RIGHT)
selected_column_headings_lbl.config(width=20)

#Left listbox, shows column headings from selected file
headers_listbox = Listbox(listbox_frame, selectmode = MULTIPLE)
headers_listbox.pack(side=LEFT)
headers_listbox.config(width=20)

#Right listbox, shows selected column headings
headers_listbox_selected = Listbox(listbox_frame, selectmode = MULTIPLE)
headers_listbox_selected.pack(side=RIGHT)
headers_listbox_selected.config(width=20)

#Buttons to add and remove current selections from respective listboxes
add_selection_btn = Button(listbox_btn_frame, text = "Add Current Selection", command = add_selection)
add_selection_btn.pack(side=LEFT)
add_selection_btn.config(width=20)
remove_selection_btn = Button(listbox_btn_frame, text = "Remove Current Selection", command = remove_selection)
remove_selection_btn.pack(side=RIGHT)
remove_selection_btn.config(width=20)

#Buttons to add and remove all items from their respective listboxes
add_all_btn = Button(listbox_btn_frame_2, text = "Add All", command = add_all)
add_all_btn.pack(side=LEFT)
add_all_btn.config(width=20)
remove_all_btn = Button(listbox_btn_frame_2, text = "Remove All", command = remove_all)
remove_all_btn.pack(side=RIGHT)
remove_all_btn.config(width=20)

#Label "Select the columns you would like to anonymize"
get_suggestions_lbl = Label(window, text="Would you like to scan the file for sensitive data?")
get_suggestions_lbl['font'] = bold_font
get_suggestions_lbl.grid(column=0, row=9, pady=(15, 10))
get_suggestions_lbl.config(width=40)

#Button: "Scan File", starts scan_file func
get_suggestions_btn = Button(window, text = "Scan File", command = scan)
get_suggestions_btn.grid(column = 0, row = 10, pady=(0, 10))
get_suggestions_btn.config(width=20, height=2)

#Button: "Anonymize", starts anonymize func
anonymize_btn = Button(window, text = "Anonymize", command = anonymize)
anonymize_btn.grid(column = 0, row = 11, pady=(0, 10))
anonymize_btn.config(width=20, height=2)

progress_bar = Progressbar(window, orient = 'horizontal', length = 286, mode = 'determinate')
progress_bar.grid(column = 0, row = 12, pady  =2)
progress_bar["maximum"] = 100
progress_bar["value"] = 0

#Button to quit the program
quit_btn = Button(window, text = "Quit", command = close_window)
quit_btn.grid(column = 0, row = 20)
quit_btn.config(width=10, height=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your `main.py`

Comment: Edited the post to include my main.py.

Comment: I removed your local modules 'modify_data_pandas' and put in dummies and was able to get your tkinter windows just fine. My impression is that it is your runtime environment that is playing up. If you are running in Windows Linux Shell tkinter will not work. In that case I would install Anaconda and run the program in a Windows Powershell after `conda activate`

Comment: After installing you say "yet the issue remains." but then you show a completely different error message. Are you asking about the "no module" error or the "no display" error? The "no display" error has been asked many times on this site, have you searched for answers?